# Angular2 and TypeScript error "Property METHOD_NAME does not exist on type 'typeof CLASS_NAME'

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I need some help. I'm playing with basics of Angular2 and TypeScript as a part of my switch from A1 to A2 so something here might be obvious for you.

I have a this situation:

1. Webpack in use.
2. `AppConfigConst` holds some static, app wide configuration data.
3. `AppConfigurationInjectable` takes `AppConfigConst` and exposes simple API to access configuration data.
4. `SelectedLanguageInjectable` want's to use method from `AppConfigConst` and here I get this:

> ERROR in [default] C:_DEV\XXX\src\app\shared\selected-language\selected-language.injectable.ts:9:46 Property 'getSupportedUiLanguages' does not exist on type 'typeof AppConfigurationInjectable'.

[image]

Comment: First of all paste code into questions, not screenshots. The issue is `private appConfiguration **=** AppConfigurationInjectable`. `=` should be `:`, since `=` defines default value for the parameter, not its type.

Comment: ...and your `selectedLang` is set as a string... shouldn't it be an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a mistake in your constructor. It should be:

```
constructor(private appConfiguration: AppConfigurationInjectable){
```

change `=` with `:`

`:` is for defining types in typescript `=` is for setting a value as you know.

Comment: Specifically (in this case) a default function argument. So the `appConfiguration` variable winds up referring to the `AppConfigurationInjectable` interface/class itself rather than an instance.